# How to import RSA key from KEY file

Tags: c#, rsa

I need to encrypt string in my app using RSA key from file .key.
It contains something like this:

```
---BEGIN RSA PRIVAET KEY---
MIICHATIABBgQDi+.....OKh4=
---END RSA PRIVATE KEY---
```

So, I know that I can use `RSACryptoServiceProvider` class to encrypt my string, but how can I import key from .key file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Bouncycastle C# crypto library, specifically the PEMReader class. `PEMReader.readObject()` will read it in and return an AsymmetricCipherKeyPair containing the private and public keys. You can then use the `DotNetUtilities` class to convert to .NET objects.